# Javascript Export Table to Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I am trying to output a table to excel using JavaScript. For some reason, it will output the first row, which is the column headings, but it doesn't get the subsequent data rows.

This is the code that gets the information from a php page, and then outputs it to the screen in a table.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    range = "30days";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getHash.php',
        data: 'value=' + range,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            // We get the results back and store details;
            hash = result;
            //We need to clear the text already on the screen
            $("#hashDetails").text("");

            $("#hashDetails").append("<br/><br/><table width=1400 align=center id='hashTable'><tr><td align=center width=200><b>UPC</b></td><td align=center width=200><b>TAG</b></td><td align=center width=200><b>SKU</b></td><td align=center width=200><b>PKG</b></td><td align=center width=200><b>LOCATION</b></td><td align=center width=200><b>QUANTITY</b></td><td align=center width=200><b>LAST TIME SHIPPED</b></td></tr>");
            for (var i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
                $("#hashDetails").append("<tr class='bottom'><td width=200 align=center class='bottom'>" + hash[i][0] + "</td><td width=200 align=center class='bottom'>" + hash[i][1] + "</td><td width=200 align=center  class='bottom'> " + hash[i][2] +"</td></td><td width=200 align=center  class='bottom'> " + hash[i][3] +"</td></td><td width=200 align=center  class='bottom'> " + hash[i][4] +"</td></td><td width=200 align=center  class='bottom'> " + hash[i][5] +"</td></td><td width=200 align=center  class='bottom'> " + hash[i][6] +"</td></tr>");
            }
            $("#hashDetails").append("</table>");
        }   ,
    });

    $('input[type=radio]').live('change', function() { alert('error'); });

});
```

This is the code that exports the table to Excel:

```
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

For the most part, it does work, as in it downloads an excel spreadsheet to the customer's computer. When I try to open the spreadsheet it says:

" The file you are trying to open, download.xls, is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

If I click Yes, it opens the file with just the column headings in row 1:

UPC TAG SKU PKG LOCATION    QUANTITY    LAST TIME SHIPPED

Comment: why not export a CSV or TSV instead of a bad html file? you can also export a simple html table (w/o office crap) and that should open without security complaints. you might also want to grab the tbody and thead apart from each other and concat them into the output file. the plain table>tr>td tables i've opend work, but not i've tried with thead and tbody like you'll get from .innerHTML...

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: cool, i just got a chance to get back to ya. glad it worked out...